# Is it safe to reuse the same nonce for decryption an indefinite amount of times in this context?

Tags: passwords, salt, nonce, chacha, scrypt

I'm creating a password management application and I'm considering using the following procedure to keep passwords safe:

1. Asking the user for `raw_password`, for example "MyLongMasterKeyPassword"
2. Generating `master_key` from `raw_password` with Scrypt and a random `salt`
3. Storing the `salt` (kept public)
4. Asking for `raw_message` (the password to store)
5. Generating `cipher` using AEAD-ChaCha20Poly1305IETF and generating a random `nonce`, and then asking for `AD`(Additional authentication)
6. Storing the `nonce`
7. Encrypting `raw_message` with `cipher`, `nonce`, and `AD`, then using the `nonce` once for encryption, that returning `cipher_text`
8. Storing the `cipher_text`
9. Decrypting `cipher_text` with stored `salt` and `nonce`, then asking for `AD` and `raw_password` to regenerate the `master_key` with the stored `salt`, and then generating a `cipher` with the `master_key` and stored `nonce`, which returns the `decrypted_message` (a password, probably)

Now, the question is, is this procedure safe? Specifically, is it safe to re-use the same nonce for decryption an indefinite amount of times, if you only use it once for encryption?

Comment: [Never use a nonce again with the same key ](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/78442/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka even if it is only used for decryption?

Comment: To use the same nonce in decryption you need to use the same nonce in encryption.

Comment: @kelalaka The salt, cipher_text, and nonce are stored. The cipher_text will be encrypted once and decrypted multiple times, and the nonce is used in this process; thus, the nonce is only used once for encryption and an indefinite amount of times for decryption. Is this safe?

Comment: Nonce = Number used once. The golden rule is a nonce must not be used under the same key again. This is for encryption. Nobody can prevent you from decrypting a ciphertext again and again. Theoretically decrypting once or twice or more are same. They should give the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Specifically, is it safe to re-use the same nonce for decryption an indefinite amount of times, if you only use it once for encryption?

Indeed, all good security definitions (under which ciphers are proven secure) will place no restrictions on the input of the decryption algorithm. The intution behind this is that the the input to the encryption algorithm will be send over the network at which point *anything* can happen to it.

Security only breaks down if you encryption *two different messages* using the same key-nonce pair.

> Now, the question is, is this procedure safe?

Yes. In fact the encryption scheme is essentially a reinvention and instantiation of [PKCS#5's PBES2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8018#section-6.2) which is [provably secure](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/196)<sup>1</sup> (even if you were to use a fixed nonce). Your parameter choice in this case is to use randomized-nonce ChaCha-Poly for encryption and scrypt for key-derivation.

---

<sub>1: Our local pedants may note that the security definition of LORX from that paper only implies CPA-security, but an extension to CCA-security definitions should be straightforward as the proof essentially relies on hiding the key from the adversary and then "inheriting" the encryption scheme's security properties.</sub>